# Getting a type error when attempting to move a file

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to move a file into a folder with this code

```
function addImage_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% get the file to add to another folder
[baseName, folder] = uigetfile();
% get the full file path of the file to add
fullFilePath = fullfile(folder, baseName);
% get the full folder path of the folder currently selected in the listbox
selectedFolder = get(handles.folders,'string');
selectedFolder = selectedFolder{get(handles.folders,'value')};
% move the file to the folder
moveFile(fullFilePath, selectedFolder);
```

And receiving this error

```
Undefined function 'moveFile' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in niceinterface>addImage_Callback (line 549)
moveFile(fullFilePath, selectedFolder);
```

Does anyone know what's going on? The matlab spec for movefile says that it takes strings and the code that I've used to get the folders/files has worked previously.

After 'disp'ing them I received the following output

```
D:\Downloads\44d9de8db7c840bf0f3fabc9371f9e0d.jpeg
D:\ImageViewer
```

Thanks all!

Comment: You said it yourself - the function is `movefile`, not `moveFile`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was on this for hours

Comment: ever used the `help` function? if you type `help moveFile` you will get up a help, where the filename is clearly stated as `movefile`. Also, in general matlab function names uses only lower case.

Comment: Yeah bud, just started using it after this travesty actually. Just a simple mistype, didn't even see it was moveFile to be honest.